spring kafka getting metrics to for messages published
i have set up the following config in my spring 3.3 (micrometer 1.12.5, kafka 3.2.4) application
    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, Car> objectObjectDefaultKafkaProducerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    objectObjectDefaultKafkaProducerFactory.addListener(new MicrometerProducerListener<>(meterRegistry));
    return new KafkaTemplate<String, Car>(objectObjectDefaultKafkaProducerFactory);

properties file has
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
spring.jmx.enabled=true

/metrics endpoint returns only the following
    .....
    "spring.data.repository.invocations",
    "spring.kafka.listener",
    "spring.kafka.template",
    .....
    .....

I was hoping to find a way i could get the number of messages published during a time interval
